# Как изменять свойство одного объекта при изменении другого?

Tags: javascript

Есть объект `chanels` у которого есть свойство `memoryPercent` который означает занимаемый `range` в %.

```
{
   chanelId: 1,
   rangeIn: 1,
   rangeOut: 100,
   memoryPercent: 50,
},
{
   chanelId: 2,
   rangeIn: 101,
   rangeOut: 200
   memoryPercent: 50
}
```

Изменяю `range` у одного объекта, например с `chanelId = 2`:

```
const minRange = 1
const newRangeOut = 400
const changeRange = chanels[1].rangeOut = newRangeOut
const differenceRange = chanels[1].rangeOut - chanels[1].rangeIn
const changeMemory = chanels[1].memoryPercent = differenceRange * 100 / newRangeOut // memoryPercent = 74.75%
```

В итоге `memoryPercent` изменяется только у `chanels[1]` (как и должно).

Вопрос в том, как автоматически рассчитывать процент у остальных элементов объекта при изменении одного из них?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, для начала следует определить, как именно должны измениться остальные элементы. Пересчитаться пропорционально тому, что было? Пересчитаться только соседние? Или еще как?

Например, у вас было:

```
chanelId1.memoryPercent = 10;
chanelId2.memoryPercent = 40;
chanelId3.memoryPercent = 30;
chanelId4.memoryPercent = 20;
```

Вы присвоили: `chanelId2.memoryPercent = 70`

Тогда остальные как должны быть? Если пропорционально, то они станут такими:

```
chanelId1.memoryPercent = 5;
chanelId3.memoryPercent = 15;
chanelId4.memoryPercent = 10;
```

Если затронет только соседние, то такими:

```
chanelId1.memoryPercent = 2.5;
chanelId3.memoryPercent = 7.5;
chanelId4.memoryPercent = 20;
```

А дальше... дальше при изменении берете и в цикле пересчитываете для каждого затронутого.